# Super polymorphic event schema

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to be able to track every action a user takes on my site.

An action can originate from a `visitor` or a `user` (both of which are human).

An action can affect a subject (`visitor` or a `user`)

An action can have an `object`, which can be any of the other database tables

Some examples:

`User A (actor)` assigns `User B (subject)` to `conversation (object)`

`User A (actor)` creates `team (object)`

`User B (actor)` moved `Visitor (subject)` to `group C (object)`

In my application, I want a feed of all events, and for each event, show exactly what actor, subject (if any) and object it refers to

I am thinking something like

```
create table actors ( -- contains as many rows as there are people
   int ID,
)

create table roles ( -- roles like for both human and object roles such as: Visitor, Team, User, Conversation, Group
   int ID,
   nvarchar(max) Name
)

create table actors_roles ( -- associates people with roles
   int Actor_ID, -- FK to actors.ID
   int Role_ID -- FK to roles.ID
)

create table objects ( -- associates objects with roles
   int ID,
)

create table object_roles ( -- associates objects with roles
   int Object_ID, -- FK to object.ID
   int Role_ID -- FK to roles.ID
)

create table tEvent (
   int ID,
   int Type_ID,
   int Actor_ID, -- FK to actors.ID
   int Subject_ID -- FK to actors.ID
   int Object_ID -- FK to objects.ID
)
```

Besides these tables, every record in `roles` will have a corresponding, separate table maintaining all the data related to the object with a foreign key.

I'd love to get some feedback on this structure and if it is scaleable, or perhaps, there is a better way to accomplish this?

Credit to `Daniel A. Thompson` for pushing me in this direction

Comment: Hi @Tarlen. What's the purpose of the `object_roles` table? i.e. why do you need to associate objects directly with roles?

Comment: Hi, it's to associate a context. For example: I have tables such as `conversations`, `groups`, `tags` etc. Each event happens in the context of such and I want to be able to reference this

Comment: Ah, interesting. Is it ok for an `object` to have multiple `roles`? Would it make sense for a single `object` to be both a `Team` and a `Conversation`?

Comment: Nope, every object has a single role, ie. corresponds to only 1 other 'object' table

Comment: OK. In that case, I'd drop the `object_roles` table, and instead add `Role_ID` as a relation in your `tObject` table. This way each `object` is associated with a single `role`.

Comment: Also, your schema currently allows the same `role` to be assigned to both an `object` and an `actor`. Is that desirable?

Comment: 1) would that same logic apply to the `actors_roles` table? Should I just drop that and put the relation directly on the `actors` table?

Comment: 2) I suppose it's okay, I am primarily interesting in performing polymorphic joins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117642/discussion-between-daniel-a-thompson-and-tarlen).

Comment: If you're doing this in Postgres, you should consider using table inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements, I'd propose the following schema:

```
-- roles for both human and object roles such as:
-- Visitor, Team, User, Conversation, Group
CREATE TABLE tRole ( 
   int ID,
   nvarchar(max) Name
)

-- contains as many rows as there are people
CREATE TABLE tActor ( 
   int ID,
   int Role_ID -- FK to tRole.ID
)

-- contains as many rows as there are objects 
CREATE TABLE tObject ( 
   int ID,
   int Role_ID -- FK to tRole.ID
)

CREATE TABLE tEvent (
   int ID,
   int Type_ID,
   int Actor_ID, -- FK to tActor.ID
   int Subject_ID -- FK to tActor.ID
   int Object_ID -- FK to tObject.ID
)
```